# symfony2: sent data with ajax to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

i have an input in the main of my site web that help people to search about something in my database but i want this input search like Facebook search bar .''ajax searching''
i have tried some code but without result . i was used the event keyup to search in instant .

my router is

```
acme_estm_site_espace_supr_admin_recuperer_donnes_recherche:
    path: /chercher
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeEstmSiteBundle:Default:recupererdonnesrechercheAction}
```

and this is my controller:

```
  $('#search').keyup(function(key) {
      var rac = $(this).val();

      var data = {
          request: rac
      };

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{{ path('acme_estm_site_espace_supr_admin_recuperer_donnes_recherche') }}",
          data: data,
          success: function(data, dataType) {
              alert(data);
          },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
          }
      })
  });

public function recupererdonnesrechercheAction(Request $request){

     if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()){

         echo "c est une requete ajax";

         $data = $request->request->get('request');
         echo $data;

     }

    return new Response();

}
```

but when i run it . i have an alert error :Error : Not Found

please help me 
thank you in advance

Comment: Does it change anything if you add `methods:  [POST]` in your router?

Answer (score 0):

---

Hello,
in your code i see you use `Request $request as a parameter`
And `if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()){`
to finally use `$request->request->get('request');`

I think you should do something like

```
public function recupererdonnesrechercheAction(){

     if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()){

         echo "c est une requete ajax";

         $data = $this->getRequest()->request->get('request');
         echo $data;

     }

    return new Response();

}
```

And about the route, you should remove "Action" in your method name

```
acme_estm_site_espace_supr_admin_recuperer_donnes_recherche:
    path: /chercher
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeEstmSiteBundle:Default:recupererdonnesrecherche}
```

---